# to_s method returning an unwanted "\"

Tags: arrays, ruby, inspect

I wrote a method that takes an array of numbers, adds the number 2 to it, and then returns an array of strings.

```
def add_two(array)
  new_array = array.map{|x| "#{x} + 2 =  #{x + 2}"}
  new_array.to_s
end
```

The following is a test result:

[image]

I have an unwanted `\` in my return. I am trying to figure out where the `\` is coming from. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is coming from `to_s` that you have at the end. You are converting an array of strings (which is presumably already what you want) into a single string that contains double quotations (which must be escaped by `\`). To fix it, just remove your line with `to_s`.

Answer (score 1):

Its not adding extra `\`s. `\` is escape character to escape `"` which is part of the result String. Here:

```
a = add_two(array)
# => "[\"1 + 2 =  3\", \"2 + 2 =  4\", \"3 + 2 =  5\"]"

puts a
# ["1 + 2 =  3", "2 + 2 =  4", "3 + 2 =  5"]
```

or directly:

```
puts add_two(array)
# ["1 + 2 =  3", "2 + 2 =  4", "3 + 2 =  5"]
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I "puts add_two(array)", I just get nil in my return

Comment: yes. because `puts` prints the output and returns `nil`. I did that just to explain you what's happening. In  short, you need not to worry about \ in your result. Your actual code works fine and  \  does not even exist.

Comment: I see no back slash on my output, i tried exactely what you wrote and it gave me what you are searching for.